# modify universal-image-loader

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I am using this project [universal-image-loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in order to display in a gridview several images. But I would like to modify these images with some html (for example add ads at the bottom of each images).

I saw the image are displayed by calling imageLoader.displayImage(..), in the method getView of the ImageAdapter.

I don't know what approach is better:

- add a step in displayImage(...) in order to create a webview with my image and html and transform this webview in bitmap?
- modify the getView of ImageAdapter which will create the webview and add an argument webview in displayeImage()?
- ...
- ...

I guess I don't have the choice, I have to use a webview.

Moreover in the method displayImage() of ImageLoader.java, i don't understand where the images are loaded, I guess this is somewhere in this line, but when I am looking in these methods I can't find/understand

```
    ImageSize targetSize = getImageSizeScaleTo(imageView);
    String memoryCacheKey = MemoryCacheUtil.generateKey(uri, targetSize);
    cacheKeysForImageViews.put(imageView.hashCode(), memoryCacheKey);
    Bitmap bmp = configuration.memoryCache.get(memoryCacheKey);
```

(How from a string built by an uri and ImageSize we can have a bitmap? where is the image?)

Answer (score 1):

Images are loaded asynchronously. So your code piece is just a top of complex logic. Main work is done in `LoadAndDisplayTask` class but you don't need to touch it.

For your case you can create own `BitmapDisplayer`:

- create BitmapDisplayer implementation
- implement `Bitmap display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView)` method
- in this method you can process incoming Bitmap as you want
- set result Bitmap in ImageView and return result

Set your BitmapDisplayer into configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So if I understand well, the modification on the image are down in the step 3? But how can I modify a Bitmap with HTML?

Comment: With HTML? I don't know. You can try to use canvas for drawaing on Bitmap. But if you want to use HTML then you should use WebView I guess.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to overlapping each imageview of the gridview with a webview?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help finally I just add a webview in the ImagePagerActivity and give up the idea to put in a gridview.